# NameError-os is not define

Tags: django-templates

I run my python code this is the error I got

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\ProgrammingKnowledge\myproject\myproject\settings.py", line 58, in 
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
^^
NameError: name 'os' is not defined

I try python manage.py runserver
I expected my app to run in my browser using django

Comment: just add `import os` to your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

If the library is installed in your system add it in your file using

```
import os
```

at the top before the os call

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).